# PHP MySQL Counting and sorting values

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm new here. In case I'm breaking some kind of protocol by asking the question in the wrong area or overlooking something in a previous search I apologize.

I have a table titled Art2011.

I am collecting data in three columns and would like to combine and count like values.

```
painting1      painting2       painting3
-----------------------------------------
image6         image4          image3
image4         image1          image4
image8         image1          image3
image2         image9          image6
image6         image4          image3
image4         image1          image4
image8         image1          image3
image2         image9          image6
```

How would I query, count and display the results in php to look like this?

```
image1 = 4
image2 = 2
image3 = 4
image4 = 5
etc...
```

Thank you in advance!
Michael

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT t.image, COUNT(t.image)
FROM (
   SELECT painting1 as image FROM Art2011
  UNION ALL
   SELECT painting2 as image FROM Art2011
  UNION ALL
   SELECT painting3 as image FROM Art2011
) AS t
GROUP BY t.image
```

Comment: So at that point I would have

$query = "SELECT t.image, COUNT(t.image)
FROM (
   SELECT painting1 as image
   FROM Art2011
   UNION
   SELECT painting2 as image
   FROM Art2011
   UNION
   SELECT painting3 as image
   FROM Art2011
) AS t
GROUP BY t.image"; 
  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Then do I need to run a loop to display my answer? I'm new to php and from what I've read, I'm guessing I would use a for loop?

Comment: @ain, the union should be UNION ALL. Otherwise the duplicate rows will be removed and the counts will not be accurate.

Comment: Yes, this query would return you a row per `imageX` (as you listed what would be the desired result in your post) and in PHP you'd fetch the rows until there is no more data.

Answer (score 1):

For each image, you can use this query to get the count:

`select count(1) from Art2011 where painting1 = 'image1' or painting2 = 'image1' or painting3 = 'image1'`

Comment: So at that point I would have

$query = "select count(1) from Art2011 where painting1 = 'image1' or painting2 = 'image1' or painting3 = 'image1'"; 
  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Then do I need to run a loop to display my answer? I'm new to php and from what I've read, I'm guessing I would use a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @ain's post :

```
$sql = "SELECT t.image as image, COUNT(t.image) as cnt FROM ( SELECT painting1 as image FROM Art2011 UNION ALL SELECT painting2 as image FROM Art2011 UNION ALL SELECT painting3 as image FROM Art2011 ) AS t GROUP BY t.image"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['image']." = ".$row['cnt']."\n";
}
```

Comment: Can I fit an ORDER BY in here? I have a total of 106 images and the results so far look like image1 = 15
image10 = 10
image100 = 5
image2 = 21
image20 = 36
image21 = 38
image22 = 109
image23 = 14
image24 = 58  I would just like to display them in order according to title#.

Comment: @user955807, you'll probably want to append something like `ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(t.image, 6) AS SIGNED)`.